# iOS 7 phone-number link doesn't work when webpage is on the home screen

Tags: web-applications, phone-number, homescreen, ios7, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have phone number links as +xx-xxx-xxxxxx on my webpage.
In iOS 7 it works as long as it is viewed in mobile safari. As soon as I've added the webpage to my homescreen (standalone webapp-mode) the links don't work anymore.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: How does your HTML look like?

Comment: Same problem here, seems like it is impossible to open links with that point to external apps (safari, phone, mail, etc) within standalone web apps.

Comment: Apparently IOS7 update broke all external links for standalone web apps. I hope Apple sees this as a bug and not a feature.

Answer (score 1):

tel: links do no work in iOS fullscreen mode. This has been a known bug for a couple months now, and no fixes have been issued as of yet, and no statement has been made yet by Apple about the status of this (major) bug.

Source: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

EDIT: Fixed as of iOS 7.0.4